# Show this function is convex

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Show that $f(x)=\frac{(\theta-x)\log_{x}\frac{x-\theta}{1-\theta}+x}{1-x}, ~x\in(\theta,\infty)$ is convex, where $\theta\in(0,1)$. $f(1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)$. Numerical experiments suggest it is, but the second order derivative is too messy to yield anything interesting. Is there a way to get around the heavy algebra of taking the derivatives? Thanks!

Comment: What about directly trying to prove the "standard" definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)?

Comment: I tried it before, but that does not seem to pan out either. The log function is not so easy to work with.

Comment: Do you really mean "log to the base $x$" ?